# Histogram of timestamps using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp

Assume that that my documents all have a (*milliseconds*) `timestamp` field given as an `int`. I want to find how many documents I have per hour, but starting at half-past an hour. In some more details: Assume that the first interesting time stamp, `minTS`, is: `1423747800000` (or Thu, 12 Feb 2015 13:30:00 GMT) and that `maxTS` is now. If I run the following aggregation:

```
"aggs": {
  "time": {
    "histogram": {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "interval": 3600000,
      "min_doc_count" : 0,
      "extended_bounds" : {
        "min" : minTS,
        "max" : maxTS
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the first returned bucket is `1423746000000` (i.e. Thu, 12 Feb 2015 13:00:00 GMT). If I change the `interval` to `1800000`, then I get the first buckets to start on the right time, but it's only 30 minutes long. I cannot manage to get it to work with one hour buckets that start on half past. How can I do it?

Comment: is the timestamp field somehow an actual ElasticSearch date field?

Comment: @markg: The `timestamp` field's type is `long`.

Comment: Take a look at the [pre_offset & post_offset](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_pre_post_offset) parameters of the date histogram aggregation

Comment: @ThomasCucchietti: Can you give an example how to do it? I keep getting `[14:00,15:00)` or some similar output.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is sure to break as it doesn't take into account leap year correction. Also in cases of month wise histogram too , it will needs to be given lots of additional information.
I would suggest to directly use date histogram as the value is already in the format ,  Elasticsearch stores dates as.
The following should give you better results -

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "dates": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "30m"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue with the starting time of the first bucket, but it also shortens the buckets --- each 30 minutes long. I want that the buckets will be [13:30,14:30), [14:30,15:30) etc. With this solution I get [13:30-14:00), [14:00-14:30) etc.